# how i can insert item to list in tcl from user input

Tags: tcl

Hi i'm new to tcl i'm trying to insert element to list in proc from user input and return the list and invoke it in another list 
i have tried this and i'm get

```
puts "Enter list Size"
set size [gets stdin]
set aList [fillTheList $size]

proc fillTheList {arg1 } {
    set lList {} 
    for {set i 0} {$i <= $arg1} {incr i} {
        set value [gets stdin]
        linsert $lList $i int(value)]
        puts "[lindex $lList $i]"
    }
    return $lList
}
```

and i'm getting this error in cmd

```
invalid command name "fillTheList"
    while executing
"fillTheList $size"
    invoked from within
"set aList [fillTheList $size]"
    (file "ascending.tcl" line 5)
```

Comment: You have to define the proc **before** you call it. Just move `set aList [fillTheList $size]` to the end.

Comment: @glennjackman it's work but i got this error

Comment: @glennjackman can't read "aList": no such variable
    while executing
"set aList[fillTheList $size]"
    (file "ascending.tcl" line 21)

Comment: `linsert` returns a new list. It does not update a list. You're missing a space in your `set` command

Comment: it doesn't return list or array

Comment: that's right. The `lList` variable is always empty. Re-read the first 2 sentences of my previous comment. Then read https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/linsert.htm

Comment: Your use of `int(value)` also seems suspicious. In other programming languages, that could be a function call or a type casting operation. In Tcl, it means "retrieve the item associated with the key `value` in the associative array called `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
proc fillTheList {arg1 } {
    set lList {} 
    for {set i 0} {$i < $arg1} {incr i} {
        puts -nonewline "Enter value "
        set value [gets stdin]
        lappend lList $value
        puts [lindex $lList $i]
    }
    return $lList
}

puts -nonewline "Enter list Size "
set size [gets stdin]
set aList [fillTheList $size]
```

A couple of notes:

- If you set the condition in the `for` invocation to `$i <= $arg1` it will ask for one more list item than you wanted, since `i` starts from 0.
- Instead of `lappend`, `lset lList $i $value` could be used. It used to only be able to change elements already in the list, but nowadays it can change the element after the last one in the list, extending the list by one.
- `lList` is a really bad variable name, because it is easy to mix up with names like `IList`.
- Tcl is barely typed at all. You type strings from the keyboard, those strings are entered in the list. If those strings are valid integers they can be used like integers. You don't need, and you can't, convert them.

Documentation:
[< (operator)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[for](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/for.htm),
[gets](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/gets.htm),
[incr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/incr.htm),
[lappend](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm),
[lindex](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lindex.htm),
[lset](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lset.htm),
[proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm),
[puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm),
[return](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/return.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm)